# VBA Code not working on a shared excel file

Tags: excel, vba, shared-file

I have a code shown below. Code works fine however when a share the file getting a appliaction-defined or object-defined error. Can somebody please help me with this?

```
Function SearchForFile(ByVal searchText As String, ByVal directory As String) As String
    Dim fs As Object
    Dim folder As Object
    Dim subFolder As Object
    Dim file As Object
    
    ' Replace the local file system object with a network mapping or cloud storage API
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    ' Replace the local directory path with the network share or cloud storage path
    Set folder = fs.GetFolder(directory)
    
    ' Check files in the current directory
    For Each file In folder.Files
        If InStr(1, file.Name, searchText, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            ' Return the path of the first matching file
            SearchForFile = file.Path
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next file
    
    ' Recursively search subdirectories
    For Each subFolder In folder.Subfolders
        SearchForFile = SearchForFile(searchText, subFolder.Path)
        If SearchForFile <> "" Then Exit Function
    Next subFolder
End Function
```

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: What is the **complete, exact error message**, and which line is it happening on? You have that information on the screen right in front of you. We can't see that screen from here, so it's up to you to share that information with us. It's in your best interest to make it as easy as possible for us to help you by providing the details you have available.

Comment: Yea. I'm on the west coast, and I can't see it either.

Comment: My guess would be that the problem is that VBA does not understand the filename it is getting from your *network share or cloud storage*, would that be OneDrive or Sharepoint? Sync the file to an unshared local directory and try that.

Comment: Searching file in local disk in folder, all permissions are properly set. When i share the file in excel getting error message is; Run-time error 1004, Application defined or object-defined error.